# Fourier expansion of a piecewise function and writing the result as a summation?

Tags: summation, fourier-series

I have been trying to find the fourier expansion of the below piecewise function but I'm a bit stuck. I've been able to determine its an odd function and have therefore calculated the odd coefficients , but writing the result in a summation format has me confused.

$$f(x)=\begin{cases}1+x/\pi& -\pi\le x<0 \\ 1-x/\pi & 0\le x\le\pi\end{cases} $$

I found the odd coefficients to be :

$\dfrac4{\pi^2(2n-1)^2}$

And I also worked out the first term of the expansion will be $1/2$.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I suggest you to edit the post and write the function yourself, instead of including a pic (not very well considered here). Have a look [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for a quick tutorial on how to write proper maths.

Answer (score 1):

Okay. Your function is
\begin{align}
f(x) = \begin{cases}
1-\frac{x}{\pi}, & x\in[0,\pi)\\
1+\frac{x}{\pi}, &x\in(-\pi,0]
\end{cases}
\end{align}
This is an example of a sawtooth function. We have
\begin{align}
\hat f[k] = \frac{1}{{2\pi}} \int_{x=-\pi}^{\pi} \exp(-i kx)f(x) \, \mathrm dx,
\end{align}
which concludes
\begin{align}
\hat f[k] &= \frac1\pi \Re\left(\int_{x=0}^\pi \frac{x}{\pi}\cdot \exp(-i k x) \, \mathrm dx\right) + \delta_{k,0}\\
&= \frac1{\pi^2}\, \frac{1}{k^2} \Re\left( \int_{0}^{k\pi} y\exp(-iy) \, \mathrm dy\right) + \delta_{k,0}
\end{align}
Using $\int_{0}^{k\pi} y\exp(-iy) \, \mathrm dy = iy\exp(-iy)|_{0}^{k\pi}-i\int_{0}^{k\pi} \exp(-iy)\mathrm dy=i(-1)^{k}k\pi + (-1)^{k}-1$, we get
$$
\hat f[k] = \begin{cases}
1, & k=0\\
-\frac{2}{\pi^2 k^2} , &k\in\mathrm{odd}\\
0, & \mathrm{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$
for